# How to sort using month and day using mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a date in this format.

```
08 april 1989
02 December 1984
13 January 1986
```

I would like to sort the results using month and day ,which has column "dateofb" and i sorting is like

```
13 january 1986
08 april 1989
02 december 1984
```

I have used the below code which doesn't work fine ,

```
$sel = $db->query("select * from biography where dateofb >= (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 90 DAY) order by dateofb desc limit 0,3");
```

I would like to display the 3 sorted results coming 90days.

Comment: If you used a standard date format (YYYY-MM-DD) this would be trivial to do

Comment: So you're telling us that you have a date stored in a varchar, and using month names rather than numbers - who designed this database?

Comment: Can you show the results form your query? Also, please, show the contents of datofb

Comment: @JohnConde I will reconvert db to yyyy-mm-dd format but how to implement sorting.thanks in advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21152951/how-to-sort-date-in-mysql

Similar to this question....hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to convert the `dateofb` column to `DATE` column type? This would allow you to do what you're looking for. The format you have now is invalid and would need to be converted via `STR_TO_DATE(dateofb, '%d %M %Y')`

Example:

```
$sel = $db->query("select * from biography where STR_TO_DATE(dateofb, '%d %M %Y') >= (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 90 DAY) order by STR_TO_DATE(dateofb, '%d %M %Y') desc limit 0,3");
```

^- See how gross that looks? If your `dateofb` was a `DATE` column, you could just do:

```
$sel = $db->query("select * from biography where dateofb >= (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 90 DAY) order by dateofb desc limit 0,3");
```

^- which is your original query.

Answer (score -1):

If your "dateofb" field is a DATE or DATETIME:

```
SELECT 
    *    
FROM biography
WHERE dateofb >= (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 90 DAY)
ORDER BY MONTH(dateofb), DAY(dateofb) ASC
LIMIT 0, 3
```