# How to sort Date in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a question on how to sort date in mysql. It may sound stupid as it can be done with `order by date asc`. 
In my table the date was actually stored in string with the format e.g. `Wed,2014-02-19`.
Let say I have a table like below.

```
id | user_id | date
1  |   38    | Wed,2014-02-19
2  |   38    | Wed,2014-02-26
3  |   38    | Wed,2014-02-12
4  |   38    | Wed,2014-02-05
```

for the case like above, I am still able to sort using `order by date asc` since all the dates are Wednesday. But let say one of the day is different as shown below,

```
id | user_id | date
1  |   38    | Wed,2014-02-19
2  |   38    | Wed,2014-02-26
3  |   38    | Thu,2014-02-13
4  |   38    | Wed,2014-02-05
```

mysql will sort `Thu,2014-02-13` first.

Anyway to do in mysql?

Comment: use a 'proper' date field, then this (and a LOT of of things) would be simple

Comment: it can be done if I stored all the date, explode using ',' then use array_multisort. But since the code is quite complex and developed by another programmer who quit from my company, I just try to not amend the code as much as possible. So i was finding is it a way to do in mysql.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simply sort by the part after the comma:

```
order by substring_index(date, ',', -1)
```

Answer (score 1):

[Mysql Date format function & order](http://www.geeksww.com/tutorials/database_management_systems/mysql/tips_and_tricks/mysql_dateformat_function_and_order_by.php)

you can have original date column as DATE type and can create your string format of date column as alias to it and sort it using the original date column. more clearly given in above link, Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you are using the wrong type for the date column. Are you using DATE or DATETIME or varchar for the date column? If you switch it to DATE, ASC and DESC will work properly.

Reference: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/datetime.html

Comment: it was developed by previous developer. And it has reason why he stored the data like this.

Comment: I would recommend a schema change if possible. You should never store the values like that - it is very inefficient. You can use date formatting functions to represent it any way that you wish (DayOfWeek, YY/MM/DD or whatever).

Answer (score 0):

Try converting the date field from a string to datetime using the `STR_TO_DATE` function like so:

```
SELECT id,user_id,STR_TO_DATE(date,'%W,%Y-%m-%d') AS new_date FROM 'table' ORDER BY new_date;
```